# I am getting different internet speeds on different computers with the same settings

Tags: networking, debian, grub, ipv6, crunchbang

I have two Crunchbang machines with identical `/etc/sysctl.conf` and `/etc/default/grub` files. On both of the `sysctl.conf` files I have ipv6 disabled, and the grub files are at their defaults. However, I am getting 1 Mb/s download on the desktop and 54 Mb/s download on the laptop. None of their other settings (that I know of) are any different. I need some way of diagnosing my problem, and any possible fixes you may know of.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that the desktop is pulling updates from Sid. This may be the problem.

EDIT: My internet speed on my desktop just jumped to 36 Mb/s, and I am now able to load webpages. Interestingly, the slow network speed often happens close to noon.

Comment: A longshot, but 1, 36, and 54Mbps are all 802.11a/b/g speeds. Are both machines connected via Wi-Fi? Do you or the guy in the next apartment like to microwave a burrito for lunch?

Comment: What does IPv6 have to do with this?

Comment: @MichaelHampton It speeds up the DNS lookup because when you query a DNS server with IPv6 and the server doesn't support it, it won't work, and it will fallback to IPv4. By disabling IPv6, it speeds up because it doesn't try IPv6 in the first place.

Comment: That's not true. Your system is still sending AAAA queries if it's modern, even if IPv6 network connectivity is unavailable. Not to mention you'll have to re-enable IPv6 soon anyway.

Comment: @Spiff That could be it, but I'm not gonna knock on my neighbor's door and ask if he's microwaving anything just because my internet is slow.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Why will I have to re-enable IPv6? It's been working fine with it disabled. Except for the whole slow internet thing.

Comment: Because IPv4 has run out of addresses, and in a few places people have already stopped using it and are IPv6-only. These places will only increase in number until eventually it's everywhere.